# Can i use localStorage instead of cookies and session to check if user is logged and redirect if not? JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I need to check if user is logged in and redirect him to login.html page if not. At first i used javascript cookies but im having problem if the site is accessed in IOS since cookies are disabled by default. I tried using localStorage instead and redirect if condition is met. But it's not going to the landing page.

Also, my site has 3 folders. where i have 3 log in scripts since i dont want a user to see other pages if he is logged in. Can i use different localStorage for each landing page?

Here's my code. Please feel free to edit.

index.html

```
            <script>


            localStorage.setItem('count', '1');
            localStorage.count = '1';

              localStorage.pageLoadCount == 1;

                if (localStorage.pageLoadCount == 0)
                location.href="path/login.html"

              localStorage.pageLoadCount = parseInt(localStorage.pageLoadCount) - 1;
              document.getElementById('count1').textContent = localStorage.pageLoadCount;
            </script>
```

login.html

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function test() {
            var userName = document.Form1.id.value;
            var password = document.Form1.pass.value;
            if ((userName=="user1") && (password=="abc123")) {

            window.open("somepath/index.html");

                } else {
                alert("Invalid ID or Password!")
                }
            }
```

Can anyone suggest me if there's anything i can use to check if user is logged without using session or cookies? i just want to be safe regarding the cookie issue in IOS.

I've been working on it for more than 48 hours now and still not getting solution. Thank you for all/any help. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: The server does not have any clue about localstorage

Comment: @epascarello thanks for answering. If server doesn't know localStorage, does it mean that I can assign one localStorage per page?